# Integrating ArcGIS Online Web map to my Java script file (test.html)?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online

Is it possible to integrate ArcGIS Online web map to my java script API?

I check the samples but in which only web map is added..

I have few layers in .html file (Like feature,dynamic etc. and I want to integrate one web map to my application.)

Comment: So, are you saying that you found the html code to embed an ArcGIS Online map into your webpage, but you want a javascript code version instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use ArcGIS Online web map in your javascript application.  There are several samples on the resource center.  One of them adds a graphicslayer, but you could also add a feature layer instead, see
 http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples_start.htm#jssamples/ags_fullmaplayout.html on how to use map.addLayer().